# How check if Google Chrome has #enable-javascript-harmony turned on

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, ecmascript-harmony

I'm trying to check if the user's from Google Chrome has activate the flag #enable-javascript-harmony.

I have no idea how to do it.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: you can test if a es6 feature exists. For example: typeof(Promise)

Comment: It's a good Idea but seams to be a work around.... what you think? is there a better solution? @Gael

Comment: it is the method employed by scripts like modernizr to check if a feature is available. And whatever, you should check any browser specific method before using it. For me, it is not just a work-around solution.

Comment: @Gael Thanks, I you are right!

Comment: Do note, any feature detection specific to things under the flag are a constant moving target. So, if you really need to know if the flag is on, there is no sure-fire way to know. Site's can't query flag state.

Comment: In short, check the features that you want use, regardless of how they are brought on the environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome flag `enable-javascript-harmony` turns on the V8 switch `--harmony`.

You can check if it is enabled by testing some ES Next functions from http://node.green (with a flag in the first column), e.g.:

```
const regexGreekSymbol = /\p{Script=Greek}/u;
regexGreekSymbol.test('π');
```

This returns `true` when ES Harmony is turned on and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\p{Script=Greek}/: Invalid escape` otherwise.