# Cannot enable google chrome's flag "Experimental JavaScript" via command line/puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer-sharp

I'm using puppeteer-sharp and here is my browser creation code

```cs
Browser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions {
    Headless = false,
    Args = new[] {
    "--js-flags=\"--harmony\"",
    "--flag-switches-begin",
    "--enable-features=javascript-harmony",
    "--enable-features=ExperimentalJavaScript",
    "--enable-javascript-harmony",
    "--flag-switches-end",
  }
});
```

from that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44652060/6119618) I read that `--harmony` V8 argument is enough for the needed flag to be enabled, but it isn't.

Although the arguments are passed
[image]

---

Flag is still not enabled

---

[image]

---

P.S. `--enable-features=ExperimentalJavaScript`, `--enable-features=javascript-harmony` and `--enable-javascript-harmony` I added myself making them by analogy to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249730/6119618) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50916529/6119618), not sure if these are correct usages (didn't found any documentation on this)

I am also unable to set flags when running `google-chrome` from command line `google-chrome-stable --args --flag-switches-begin --enable-features=javascript-harmony --flag-switches-end`